# Reactjs read a properties file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, file, properties

I have trouble looking for a solution on **how to read a properties file in reactJS.**

I've read that you can use the module "properties-reader" but I can't seem to make the require work. Is there a simple way ?

For example,

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './properties.file';
// var propertiesUser = properties.get('user');
class Main extends Component {

  render() {
    // Change title
    document.title = "Milo's Collection"

    return (
      <div>
        {propertiesUser}
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: is this 'properties file' a JSON file? if so, how are you exporting it? and when you import it what's the specific issue

Comment: yeah I can make it a json file, I just need a file where I can put a property that I use in other files, and when I change a property it'll change it in all the files
 
I mean if i import a json file, how would I use the property in a var ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a simple way to import/export an object (in a .js file) so you can re-use it across multiple files:

```
/* properties.js */

export const properties = {
    content: "This is a string"
};
```

Then in your react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { properties } from './properties.js';

class Main extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {properties.content}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This truly was very helpful

Comment: I'm doing a similar way in my project, now I need to read the properties.js from the server through a REST call and use it to map names. I'm not finding a proper solution to fetch this js file and make it available for global usage .. can you please suggest here   @Jayce444

Comment: @user1954970 well there's a few options, like putting the API call in the root app component and using context to provide it to the rest of the app. Or if you don't need the properties in React app but just in other JS files then you could add a script to your site which fetches the properties and attaches them to the `window` object. However, since your question is fundamentally different from this one, I suggest making a new question with all the relevant details, you'll have better luck getting answers that way