# properties file in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a few fixed/final variables in my React application. I need to put them in a properties file and read from that for the application. 
Since I'm new to React, I don't know how to create a properties file and the location it needs to be placed.

Secondly, I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706241/reactjs-read-a-properties-file) and it didn't help since I was not able to use the defined property in a way other than mentioned in this.

Kindly guide me through the process of creating variables in the properties file. If the above mentioned way is suitable, then please suggest a way to use these variables as well (say assigning to another variable, or fetching and using it elsewhere).

Here are some of the things I've tried:

created a js file and put

```
export const properties = {
    value: 1
};
```

Then, tried to read that by using

```
var valueInOtherClass = {properties.value}
```

This gives an error.

Comment: Could you post some code showing what you've tried? That would be helpful.

Comment: @JakeWorth I have edited to include what I've tried

Comment: How are you importing `properties`? "This gives an error" -> what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
const properties = {
prop1: value,
porp2: value2,
prop3: value3
}
export default properties;
```

Now, you can use these properties anywhere, such as:

```
import properties from 'yourPath';
```

and use array destructuring like:

```
const {prop1} = properties;
```

or any something like:

```
const myProperty = properties.prop1;
```

What I do is generally I create a configurations folder in my project and place such files with proper names and use these variables as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as you're expecting with the curly braces `var valueInOtherClass = {properties.value}` it's also better practice to explode out your variables like in the following,

```
import properties from './foo/bar/something'
const {value} = properties
```

Also you could choose to use environment variables instead using something like https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables inside of a `process.env` and used liked the following:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <small>You are running this application in <b>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</b> mode.</small>
      <form>
        <input type="hidden" defaultValue={process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```