# How to read global key value properties in a React application

Tags: reactjs, properties-file

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Reactjs read a properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706241/reactjs-read-a-properties-file)

I want to create global properties in order for utils classes to read and configure themselves. My goal is to avoid getting these values via a constructor, so other developers won't need to touch the code, and will be able to config some global configurations via some external means.

I read about setting environment variables, but I don't want people to start setting these variables, but use something more local to the app.

I have also read about an NPM package called `properties-reader` but it seems to work for Node.js only?

So how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just create a **gitignored** file `config/local.js`.
This file will just export an config object

```
// config/local.js
export default {
   apiUrl : "...",
   ...,
}
```

And then, in your utils file

```
// utils file
import config from 'config/local';

config.apiUrl;
```

Each developer will have a local configuration.

Is it a solution for you ?

Of course, you'll have to add local.js in each environment.

Comment: since I'm new at this I'm still not sure.. what about when I want to release the app to production?

Comment: yes, your production environment will have his own local.js file too. That's a known pattern. Each environment will have its own configuration with its own values.

Comment: It's up to you to set up with your CI this process

Comment: Can't the config be inspected when deploying the application?